# Poisson distribution probability question with conditionals

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be the number of times Gerald emits a queef in any given hour. The problem gives that $X$~$Poisson(\lambda)$. If Gerald arrives at noon and queefs at least once by 1 PM when he has to leave, what is the probability he queefs twice before he leaves?

Not sure where to begin this problem. I know I will have to use conditional probability but not really sure how to set this up. Is it correct if I say that the desired probability is $P(X = 2, X > 0)/P(X>0) = P(X=2)/(1-P(X=0))$?

Comment: @copper.hat And if Gerard is a she? Is it appropriate?

Comment: I decided to remove my remarks in case someone might feel slighted. I do, however, believe this is the first time I have seen the work queef used on MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $X$ is a Poisson($\lambda$). Given Gerald comes at noon and has to leave at $1$PM this means Gerald has one hour. Also given that Gerald has to queef at least once and the question asks us to find the probability of the number of queefs in that hour being $2$. Your answer is absolutely correct. We need
$$P(X = 2\mid X\geqslant1) = \frac{P(X=2,\ X\geqslant1)}{P(X\geqslant1)} = \frac{P(X=2)}{1-P(X=0)}$$
We know that for a Poisson random variable, $P(X=k) = \dfrac{\lambda^ke^{\lambda}}{k!}$, therefore
$$\text{Required probability} = \frac{\lambda^2e^{\lambda}}{2(1-e^{\lambda})}$$